# Why is the print() function not echoing to console?

Tags: python, scrapy

I haven't written any Python code in over 10 years. So I'm trying to use Scrapy to assemble some information off of a website:

```
import scrapy

class TutorialSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://example.com/page/1',
            'https://example.com/page/2',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            print(f'{self.name} spider')
            print(f'url is {url}')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        self.log(response.url)
        sys.stdout.write('hello')
```

I'm trying to parse the url in the `parse` method. What I can't figure out is, why will those simple `print` statements not print anything to stdout? They are silent. There doesn't seem to be a way to echo anything there back to the console, and I am very curious about what I am missing here.

Comment: how do you use this class ?

Comment: Are you actually calling any of these functions/methods?  As it currently is, your code appears to just define a class and not do anything with it.

Comment: Someone please explain to me how my question should be closed as "off topic". With regard to the indentation, it's correct where I pasted it from and I corrected it here.

Comment: It's a sample class designed to get one up and running with Scrapy. It is used from the command like like this: ```scrapy crawl tutorial```. My question isn't so much about Scrapy in particular as it is just a general Python question about why I am not getting expected behavior.

Comment: In your sample code, you don't appear to create an instance of your class or call any of its methods

Comment: What makes you think the `parse()` method is even being called? Please [edit] your question again and add code showing how the class is actually being **used**.

Comment: Scrapy encourages the use of the [`logging`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-from-spiders) module, and it would seem like the asynchronous nature of the spiders is messing with `print` and `stdout.write` so logging seems to be the way to go. You use the builtin logger already, so you may just not be finding those logging messages.. I'd suggest creating your own logger so separate your messages out from the built in ones anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both requests you're doing in your spider receive `404 Not found` responses. By default, Scrapy ignores responses with such a status and your callback doesn't get called.

In order to have your `self.parse` callback called for such responses, you have to add the `404` status code to the list of handled status codes using the `handle_httpstatus_list` meta key (more info [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-handle_httpstatus_list)).

You could change your `start_requests` method so that the requests instruct Scrapy to handle even 404 responses:

```
import scrapy

class TutorialSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://example.com/page/1',
            'https://example.com/page/2',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            print(f'{self.name} spider')
            print(f'url is {url}')
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [404]},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        self.log(response.url)
        sys.stdout.write('hello')
```